# Image is going Outside of Bootstrap Grid and less Responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

Hello im building my website with bootstrap 4 and while using the grid system I noticed the image goes outside of the grid system a little. (Screenshot below) Because of this in ipad mode everything looks too close together. I know I can add some media queries but I thought the whole point of bootstrap grid is to make everything responsive automatically without having to use media queries.

Screenshot and Code Below but you can also see it live here http://vdfml.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html

[image]

```
<header id="showcase">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- girl -->
      <div class="girl-container col-sm-12 col-md-5 .col-lg-6">
        <img src="img/french_girl.png" class="girl" alt="" />
      </div>
      <!-- text -->
      <div class="text-container col-sm-12 col-md-7 .col-lg-6">
        <h1 class="">
          Authentic, European-Inspired <br />
          Bakery Goods
        </h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Order Online</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <!-- </div> -->
    <!-- BOTTOM CURVE -->

    <div class="bottom-curve">
      <svg
        id="Layer_1"
        data-name="Layer 1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 1334.16 101.52"
      >
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: #fff;
              fill-rule: evenodd;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path
          class="cls-1"
          d="M-24.49,42.52C41.88,62.86,318.79,98.6,665.09,41S1231.94-18.55,1309,67.66v33.87H-25.2S-24.49,94.72-24.49,42.52Z"
          transform="translate(25.2 -0.01)"
        ></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- BOTTOM CURVE -->
</header>

CSS


    #showcase .row {
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        /* padding: 0 10rem; */
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    #showcase .girl-container {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #showcase .girl{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 80%;
        /* width: 35rem; */


    }

    #showcase .text-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    }

    #showcase .text-container h1 {
    font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
    color: #ee3844;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    line-height: 1;
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
    text-shadow: 
    1px  1px     #fff, 
    -1px  1px     #fff, 
    1px -1px     #fff, 
    -1px -1px     #fff,
    1px  1px 5px #555;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
```

Comment: By the way I forgot to mention. I know I could add img-fluid class so the image width can adjust with the grid but I wanted the image to be a specific height of 90% tall of its container.